# OUI Lookup Database for android

Tags: java, android, lookup, mac-address, vendor

I know this question is asked several times here but I didn't find any helpful answer 
I'm working to develop an application in which I'm search wifi connected devices and I have to show vendor names of each device there are some APIs like

http://api.macvendors.com/00:5a:13:72:3f:64

which provide lookup against each MAC address but I can't afford to trigger that API for each device
 I want to download OUI database once or want to add in my app that when I open app all data already be there for lookup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to download XML File located here [Cisco vendorMacs.xml](http://macvendors.co/vendormacs)
One more source for the same file [Cisco vendorMacs.xml updated](https://devtools360.com/en/macaddress/vendorMacs.xml)

It contains updated and complete OUI database.

Disclaimer: I'm the founder of this website

Comment: Well, many thanks Samy. It work perfectly, i compared with latest Nmap OUI list, 100% match correct on my tests.